# Regex not matching

Tags: sed, regular-expression

why this does not match..?

```
sed -e '/--Updated?[[:space:]]+Date/d' inputfile
```

this..:

```
--Updated Date: 2013-11-06 15:32:13
```

`d?` is because sometimes I have `Update Date`, and sometimes `Updated Date`.

for removal? I have tried with `\s` too, not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to use the `-r` parameter.
try use

```
sed -r '/--Updated?[[:space:]]+Date/d' inputfile
```

**updating answer**

When you use `sed '/something/d'` , every line that match with this will be deleted.

`-r`  - the parameter -r is use extended regular expressions .

Inside the expression have 2 regular expressions.

`[[:space:]]` - Match with all whitespace characters, including line breaks

```
? - optional
```

`+` - one or more times.

SO, the command sed will delete every line that match with --updated and than one or more whitespace character and than Date but because of the ? the character d is optional.
like:

```
--Updated Date: 2013-11-06 15:32:13
--Updated   Date: 2013-11-06 15:32:13
--Updated           Date: 2013-11-06 15:32:13
--Update Date: 2013-11-06 15:32:13
```

Comment: yes that was it.

Comment: Please explain your command.It would be helpful for noobs like me.

Answer (score 5):

To do this using POSIX basic regex, the closest I can come is:

```
sed '/--Updated*[[:space:]][[:space:]]*Date/d' inputfile
```

Unfortunately there is no real substitute for `?`, so a `*` is used which would also match multiple `d`s. The `+` however can be replaced by simply repeating the pattern an using a `*` for the second repetition.

#### Update

Actually the way to get the equivalent effect of the extended expressions is to use two patterns:

```
sed \'
  /--Updated[[:space:]][[:space:]]*Date/d
  /--Update[[:space:]][[:space:]]*Date/d
  ' inputfile
```

Comment: Is there any real benefit using this, or I am good with `-r`? I am using GNU sed, so I should be safe?

Comment: @branquito, if you are sure that GNU `sed` will always be used, then you will be fine to use the extended expressions. If you will run it on another system, eg on OSX, then the `-r` option may not be in the default `sed`.

Comment: I think probably *`[d ]*`* would be a little more explicit, if not by much. It is definitely tricky.

Comment: @mikeserv, updated, just realised that the best way is just to use two patterns.

Comment: This is true, but performance-wise ( if it can be counted in this case ) it does have a negative effect as *`sed`* now has two directives to check per line. Generally though, at least in my experience this is a non-issue, as *`sed`* is probably the fastest solution in any case that involves editing. *`Grep`* might be faster in this case though if you use *`-v`*. The only times i've been disappointed with *`sed`* is when ive had a choice between using it with two outs and the *`w`* directive or *`tee`* and two concurrent *`greps`*. The latter seems always to win out.

Comment: To clarify - my *disappointment* amounted to - at maximum - only a few seconds in difference, even when applying the logic to millions of files.

Comment: Thinking again, maybe *`/--Update/{/.*--U[a-zA-Z]*[ ]*Date/d}`* - that should work, I think. At least in that way you avoid running two checks on *every* line.

Comment: @mikeserv, now you are performing two checks for every line! With my last edit, at least if the line is deleted after the first, then the second shouldn't be performed (although two checks will still happen on most lines). I see the idea you are getting at though, but I don't think it can be arranged to give any benefit in this particular case.

Comment: Yeah, im done with it. Good answer, by the way. But i dont think im doing two checks - if update isnt in it it doesn't get any further.

Comment: @mikeserv, ok, I see. You're right. I will leave this now as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With gnu sed 4.2.2 on cygwin, add the `-r` flag:

```
 '--Updated Date: 2013-11-06 15:32:13'|sed -r -e '/--Updated?[[:space:]]+Date/d'
```

prints no output.  `-r` turns on extended regular expressions so `?` and `+` will work like you expect.  The [reference for extended regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#ere) I use most points out that `?` and `+` have to have a leading backslash in basic regular expressions (the default) in order to have their special meaning.

Comment: I use the same reference, it's excellent.